# getRuntime().exec does not perform as expected

Tags: java, command-line, runtime.exec

I'm trying to get my java program to run an svn command from the command prompt, which will write logs to an xml file.

This is what I want it to do:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c svn log /location/ --xml > c:\\output.xml");
```

however, it will not print anything to the xml file.

when I enter the "svn log /location/ --xml > output.xml" directly into cmd, though, it will print the logs as expected, into the xml file.

furthermore, when I use the following code, it will print "test" into the xml file without problems.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c echo \"test\" > c:\\work\\output.xml");
```

OK, after reading When Runtime.exec() Wont, I've determined that for some reason, svn is not recognized when I run the command with java, but it is perfectly fine when I enter it manually into the command line

Any ideas?  Let me know if you have any questions that i might be able to help you with.

Comment: Are you capturing any output or errors and printing them to your logs? i.e. is `svn` failing?

Comment: Please read [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). All 4 pages. Then please edit your question to include detail about the *real* problem.

Comment: ok, @BalusC, I read the 4 pages... and I understand what my problem above is, however I still can't get it to work.  In fact, I can't even get the correct solution on page 4 to work.  Perhaps I'm a complete idiot, but I need this explained to me as though I'm 2 years old, with very specific instructions on what to do.  I don't know how to describe the REAL problem, because frankly, I don't know what the real problem is.

Comment: The article should have given you insights how to capture the actual command console output (and errors, if any), like as if you're entering the command yourself in the console. *This* output should contain the answer to your problem. For example, `svn: Unknown command` or something. This information should help you in nailing down the problem better.

Comment: ok, the question is updated with important information now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try giving full path of your svn binary in the first `exec` method call.

Comment: well, I can't give you a full path, since it is a company's database... but I can tell you that it is https: //IP_address/svn/etc/

Comment: No I didn't mean path of your svn repository. What I meant was to provide full path to you svn client (`svn.exe`) inyour exec call.

Comment: Oh... yeah, that was the problem.  For some reason, putting in "c:\program files\...\svn" worked, whereas just having svn didn't work.  Thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

AFAIU (from what I've seen in similar questions on forums) redirection (`>`) does not work when used in `Runtime.exec()`.

Comment: Indeed, redirection is a feature of the shell; see also this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740390).

Answer (score 2):

Follow advise from here http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~diam/java/online/io/javazine.html

> Consider the following line of code:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/sh -c > /bin/ls > ls.out");
```

> This is intended to execute a Bourne
>   shell and have the shell execute the
>   ls command, redirecting the output of
>   ls to the file ls.out. The reason for
>   using /bin/sh is to get around the
>   problem of having stdout redirected by
>   the Java internals. Unfortunately, if
>   you try this nothing will happen. When
>   this command string is passed to the
>   exec() method it will be broken into
>   an array of Strings with the elements
>   being "/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/ls", ">",
>   and "ls.out". This will fail, as sh
>   expects only a single argument to the
>   "-c" switch. To make this work try:

```
String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "/bin/ls > out.dat"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

> Since the command line is already a
>   series of Strings, the strings will
>   simply be loaded into the command
>   array by the exec() method and passed
>   to the new process as is. Thus the
>   shell will see a "-c" and the command
>   "/bin/ls > ls.out" and execute
>   correctly.

I suggest that you change your command to

```
String[] cmd = {
  "cmd.exe",
  "/c",
  "c:\\path\\to\\svn log /location/ --xml > c:\\output.xml"
};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```