# Using Imagemajick in java using OS X

Tags: java, macos, imagemagick

I have imagemajick installed in OS X using macports.  When I run a convert command from the command line (bash) I am able to convert my movie to a jpg.  But when I run it via the Java Process Builder I get no such output.  What gives.  The following is the java code I use to execute the command.

```
private void run(String[] args)
    {
        try
            {
                ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);

                Process p = pb.start();

                p.waitFor();
                InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                is = p.getErrorStream();
                isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        System.err.println(line);
                    }
            }
        catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

The string passed in is /usr/local/bin/convert /Users/me/Videos/Capture-20110708-220220.mpg[0] /Users/me/Videos/out0.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You might try `redirectErrorStream()`, as shown in this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740390/printing-my-macs-serial-number-in-java-using-unix-commands/5740673#5740673), to see any diagnostic output.

Comment: See also [When `Runtime.exec()` won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).

Comment: See also [Java Tips: From `Runtime.exec()` to ProcessBuilder](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.util/from-runtime.exec-to-processbuilder.html).