# JavaFX get the version of a specific application installed in a computer

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to make an application that will get the version of an installed application. For instance, I want to get the current version of Firefox that is installed in my system. I am using JavaFX. Thanks for all the help guys!

What I was working on is a launcher that will display the version of the currently installed application and the version that is available for download.

Comment: I understand your problem, but it is _unclear what you are asking_. "How do I do this" is not a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try to run a VB script from within java. Works perfect for me, I am reading out on my Windows 7 PC the motherboards serial number with exactly the script this user here has posted :
[How can I get my motherboard's ID, using Java, in Linux, Mac, and Solaris?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13435960/how-can-i-get-my-motherboards-id-using-java-in-linux-mac-and-solaris)

Comment: Thank you for this solution!! This is all I need. :) I am happy that despite the said "unclear" question that I asked, you were able to help me out. Thanks lad! :) Cheers!