# Creating and executing batch file and linking the output to a progress bar

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a Java swing GUI, which takes few parameters from user (through text fields) and stores them in a string called `finalstring`. This string is basically a command, which runs an ".exe" file with few parameters. Now i want to **create a batch file(start.bat on my desktop), in which i want to copy this string**. **Finally i want to execute this batch file. Along with the execution, i also want to store the output of this batch file.**
Also, the batch file executes certain process, which i want to link with progress bar, is this possible?(**process running in batch file, to be linked to java swing's progress bar**?).

I did all above things using python and tkinter as GUI, but during the storage of output of batch file, my tkinter gui used to hang(not responding), so i am switching to java swings GUI.
I searched most of the online threads, but nothing is going in my head(created few java programs also, but the batch file is not being created), so i want help, i appreciate your effort to go through this thread.

Comment: Sounds like a horrible design. And I would even say that Java is not the right language for that. Try .NET, it has better connections to the OS.

Comment: *"is this possible?"* - The way you described, I wouldn't think so.  If you were determined to run this from Java (which would give you access to a progress bar), then yes, it would require some decent library code (executing a command, getting the output, etc), but it would be doable.

Comment: Its ok if i dont connect the output stream to progress bar, but atleast mention the code to create new batch file with "finalstring" in it..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can execute your batch using [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5740673/230513). You can `append()` lines from the combined output stream to a `JTextArea`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513).

I'm not sure you can usefully display progress in a [`JProgressBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) without knowing more about the granularity of the process.