# Get Motherboard Serial/ID On Linux Machine With Java For Anti-Piracy Usage

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, web-applications, ubuntu

I am using this code to get Motherboard ID in windows :

```
public static String getMotherboardSN() {
    String result = "";
    try {
        File file = File.createTempFile("realhowto", ".vbs");
        file.deleteOnExit();
        FileWriter fw = new java.io.FileWriter(file);

        String vbs = "Set objWMIService = GetObject(\"winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\cimv2\")\n"
                + "Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ \n"
                + " (\"Select * from Win32_BaseBoard\") \n"
                + "For Each objItem in colItems \n"
                + " Wscript.Echo objItem.SerialNumber \n"
                + " exit for ' do the first cpu only! \n" + "Next \n";

        fw.write(vbs);

        fw.close();
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath());
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p
                .getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            result = line;
        }
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result.trim();
}
```

Trying this code in ubuntu server throws an exception :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cscript": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:615)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:448)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:345)
    at tcs.util.MiscUtils.getMotherboardSN(MiscUtils.java:31)
    at tcs.util.Validator.validate(Validator.java:13)
    at test.Shoot.main(Shoot.java:31)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1021)
```

I have googled about it but found no solution for linux . I also tried solutions here [Printing my Mac's serial number in java using Unix commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740390/printing-my-macs-serial-number-in-java-using-unix-commands/5740673#5740673) and still no luck.
I am aware that there are solutions written in C/C++ but using JNI is not an option because we have no experience in it and cant meet the deadline on time.
any suggestions will be appreciated,

Comment: What would happen when using this code inside some VM?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch which code? which VM? can you explain some more please?

Comment: You can run any OS (including Windows) inside virtual machines (like VMWare, Qemu, ....)

Comment: Try `dmidecode`, however don't ever think you are protecting your software

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i am not sure what you are suggesting . run my program inside VM ?

Comment: @dtmilano what do you suggest then?

Comment: *"I have googled about it but found no solution for linux"*  Never mind.  As far as anti-piracy goes, you haven't really got a solution for Windows either.

Comment: @dave - he is suggesting this: http://linux.die.net/man/8/dmidecode.  But as Andrew implies, this is all pretty futile.  Serial numbers can be spoofed / changed.

Comment: Wait, `cscript` throws an error on Ubuntu? I wonder where that is coming from... http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cscript/info

Answer (score 0):

use "cscript" command with absolute path

FULL_PATH/cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath())

example:   /home/myprojext/cscript //NoLogo " + file.getPath())