# Apple Macintosh hardware information using script

Tags: macos, lotusscript

I am writing a LotusScript agent to obtain machine hardware information for a Windows machine. So far i am using standard Windows APIs to get the data. Are there any similar ways to do the same on a Apple Mac?

Answer (score 0):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5740673/230513), you can examine the output of [`ioreg`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ioreg.8.html).