# Passing args into a executable Unix file (MacOS)

Tags: java, macos, unix, arguments, terminal-emulator

First of all, I had some issues on the process, but the one I want to fix is passing some terminal arguments into Java:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash",
    "-c",
    "/User/me/path/to/Binaryfile/binfile",
    "-o this -a is -z specific -m kind -y of -kl arguments -i want "
);
```

If i run with this code,

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash",
    "-c",
    "/User/me/path/to/Binaryfile/binfile"
);
```

I get the execution of the binary file. Remember I'm using a Mac, and I want to run the binary with some specific args of this one. Sorry, if my English is bad.

Comment: A complete example is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5740673/230513).

Comment: im kinda new at unix console, its a bit hard to me to understand the argumentens they are passing into the process builder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this concrete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5740673/230513), three arguments are passed:

- `"bash"`
- `"-c"`
- `"ioreg -l | awk '/IOPlatformSerialNumber/ { print $4;}'"`

Unless you need the shell to interpret your arguments, you can probably do something like this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/User/me/path/to/Binaryfile/binfile",
    "-o xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx", "-u xxxxx", "-p xxxx");
```

Comment: "[2013-12-03 11:58:17] Unexpected extra commandline arguments
 [2013-12-03 11:58:17] Unexpected extra commandline arguments "   
i get this output
And if i place this:
<code>ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("bash","-c",/User/me/path/to/Binaryfile/binfile,"-o http://xx.xxx.xx.xxx:xxxx" ,"-u xxxxx"," -p xxxxx" );</code>, the outout is:<i> Error opening terminal: unknown.</i>

Comment: I don't understand why you're running a sub-shell; see updated example.

Comment: i have a binary file, and when im running it i have to insert some args in the shell, and i want to start the binary with fixed args with the java

Comment: with your code i get this output :Error opening terminal: unknown...I dont need to call the bash or -c?

Comment: PS: Dont forget the fact im doing this on a macOS

Comment: Same here; for reference, I tested with `new ProcessBuilder("head", "-n 10", "build.xml")`.