# How to get system level information from OSX with java

Tags: java, macos, wmi

I am making a program with java that gets system level information and reports it back to the user. It is currently only working on Windows operating systems because I'm using something called [jWMI](http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/) which is dependent on [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I'm interested in making my program compatible with OSX, but without WMI, I don't know how to get system level information such as total PHYSICAL RAM not the amount of ram dedicated to the jvm. As well as the ram form factor, the maximum PHYSICAL RAM upgrade, the computer and processor manufacturer and model. I need a way to get that information whether it's through something similar to jWMI or if it's something that's built right in to OSX that you can call with java. I don't know anything about OSX and the different versions, so if I need to clarify something just let me know and I will be more than happy to edit this or reply to you to help clear things up.

Comment: probably using `ioreg` and `ProcessBuilder` [this answer has an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740390/printing-my-macs-serial-number-in-java-using-unix-commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe SIGAR is of help? It works for a variety of operating systems, including OS X.
https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home