# How to describe content of file rar / zip in jtable from url or path(directory)?

Tags: java, swing, zip, jtable, rar

How to describe content of file rar/zip in jtable from url or path directory in java?
I found [here](http://www.adarshr.com/papers/raroscope) and [here](http://www.javareference.com/jrexamples/viewexample.jsp?id=79)
But how to open from URL on describe to jtable?

Comment: And what are you going to do if the rar/zip contains folders (with subfolders, .... ). A file structure is typically shown in a `JTree` instead of a `JTable`

Comment: well, Good Idea, have a references ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `PrpcessBuilder`, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9832473/230513), to execute `unzip -l` or `unrar -l` and parse the output to create my `TableModel`. See also [*How to Use Tables*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to model the data some how.  Maybe a `VirtualFile`, this should contain the information you want to display.

You then need to create a model of the that wraps this data in some meaningful way.  You'll need a [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html) for this purpose (preferably use the [Abstract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) or [Default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) implementation)

Once you've decided on how you want the model to be laid out, you simply supply the modle to the [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)

For more information check out [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

**UPDATE**

You can learn more from the [Basic I/O lesson](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/), but here's a (really) basic example of reading the contents of URL to local disk

```
File outputFile = new File("Somefile on disk.rar");
Inputstream is;
OutputStream os;
try {
    is = url.openStream();
    os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesIn = -1;
    while ((bytesIn = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {

        os.write(buffer, 0, bytesIn);

    }

    os.flush();
} catch (IOException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
    try {
        os.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
}
```

Comment: And then, how to open file from URL ? because the type is file, and file not compatible with url type ?

Comment: Well, if the `URL` is not a reference to a file on the local system you could grab the `URL`'s `InputStream` and copy it locally, then reference the local copy via a `File` object

Comment: maybe it will spend a lot of memory, but have a references ?
i newbie in java, this is my first project in java